# Getting this error on checkout page in magento2

Tags: magento2

> 1 exception(s): 
>   Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException):
>   Element 'block',
>   attribute 'name': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'Question Block' is not
>   accepted by the pattern '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z\d-_.]*'. Line: 1816

Comment: can you share me what you change?

Comment: where i check   knkn

Comment: I mean where you get error? when you installed and then it comes or may be you were changed some code.